# How to manage loop of request-response dialog with server

Tags: java, http, stream, client-server

I'm writing a simple client-server system and the question is: how to structure my client code in order to get POST request-response working in a loop?

At the moment it looks something like this (and it's is NOT a loop right now):

1. open HttpURLConnection
2. set properties
3. setDoOutput(true)
4. writing to output stream
5. closing output stream
6. new DataInputStream
7. reading response
8. exiting method

I'm not sure which objects do I have to save for the next iterations and which ones I should close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to save the connection object and you should  make use of `setDoInput(true)` for reading data but if you just want to read `responseCode` and `responseMessage` you dont need `InputStream`. check the code below.

```
HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)new URL("url").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml"); // depend on you
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml, application/xml"); // depend on you
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write(yaml);
writer.close();
int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
String message = connection.getResponseMessage();
```

for `InputStreamReader`

```
connection.setDoInput(true);
InputStreamReader reader =  new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
char[] cbuf = new char[100];
reader.read(cbuf); 
// there are 3 read method you can choose as per your convenience 
//and put a check for end of line in while loop for reading whole content. 
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, while this is not exactly what I was looking for, but I've learned that I don't have to open data input stream to get a response

Answer (score 1):

After managing my own 'research' on this subject (thanks to Google and Nokia Developer forums) I've come to the final view of my code. It's a file upload loop:

```
path = Paths.get(requestString);
in = Files.newInputStream(path);

int i = 0;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) { 
    URL u = new URL(defaultURL);
    huc = 
        (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
    huc.setDoOutput(true);
    huc.setDoInput(true);

    os = huc.getOutputStream();
    os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    os.flush();
    os = null;

    // thanks to dku.rajkumar for the following block of code ! 
    InputStreamReader reader =  
        new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream());
    char[] cbuf = new char[400];
    reader.read(cbuf);
    reader.close();

    String s = new String(cbuf);
    messagebuffer.append(s + "\n\n");

    huc.disconnect();

    Thread.sleep(16);
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't have connection.close() and it doesn't have sleep(); those two are essential in order to escape memory leak; also your code doesn't actually have loop itself, which could be an issue too

Comment: hey common..pls dont say that I was not expected to write a test that too without know the whole requirement.. cant you put "connection.close()" and loop by yourself, it is expected to know already.

Comment: well, your 're right. if this is about rating - i'll return the mark on the question. no need to get upset :) sorry!

Comment: Its not just about rating man.. when you unaccept an answer there must be a strong reason behind it...